# How to get itemized receipt from booking.com?

Tags: online-resources, booking.com

Does anyone know how to get an itemized receipt from booking.com? When I made my reservations, I got an email confirmation showing my total and the dates (and other small things like tax %), but the receipt is not itemized (if it can even be called a receipt). My booking history info is even more sparse on booking.com itself, only showing the dates and total. How can I get it to break down the price for me showing how much I spent per night to verify to my company that I didn't have charges besides the nightly cost of the room?

Answer (score 14):

In cases where you need to show lodging charges for reimbursement or similar expense purposes, you would not use anything from booking.com or any other online site.

Instead, you have to get the final bill/receipt/folio from the property itself when you check out.  That will be itemized showing the room rate, taxes, fees and incidentals.

If the room is pre-paid, then the confirmation from booking.com should suffice since you can't have any incidentals prior to check-in.  However, you would still need the final bill since there can be legitimate charges booking.com does not collect.

Your company's travel department should be able to answer any questions you have.  They might even make the booking for you on a company card.